# Check if a range contains a value > 0 in excel

Tags: excel

In excel, i would like to check this range B2:G2, whether any cell within this range contains a value > 0, then it will returns True, else False.

Is there an excel formula that can help to achieve this? Before i am asking this question, tried different approach but no help such as: counta, sumproduct...

Comment: I have edited my answer below to reflect your need to return True or False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  There is an excel formula to achieve this.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:G2,">0"),"True","False")
```

Source: https://exceljet.net/formula/value-exists-in-a-range
[image]

Comment: Why not `=AND(COUNTIF(B2:G2,">0"))` to achieve a true boolean value?

Answer (score 4):

The `MAX()` formula can be applied to a range. Therefore, `=MAX(B2:G2)>0` will give you your answer.

Comment: Nice minimalism. Elegant and a true boolean return.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you don't want to use VBA the code below will work (although it is ugly ...)

```
    =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(B2),B2>0),TRUE,
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(C2),C2>0),TRUE,
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(D2),D2>0),TRUE,
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E2),E2>0),TRUE,
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(F2),F2>0),TRUE,
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(G2),G2>0),TRUE,FALSE))))))
```

It is just a bunch of nested if functions but it gets the job done